# Solidity, Unreachable code at ReentrancyGuard.sol:61:9 by OpenZeppelin

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I'm using **Solc 0.8.4** and received this warning, do I need to worry about it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it just means the code can't be reached.

Comment: I see, so there may come some situations in my functions which have nonReentrant modifier, is that not problematic with this warning?  I can't imagine when and how this could happen and my code become unreachable